# Php artisan - custom command

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I would like to create my own php artisan command so when I write

```
php artisan env:[variable]
```

I want to get that variable, so I can check fast if I'm getting the right variable from .env file

Is this possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a console command with:

`php artisan make:console`

As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan).

You are probably better off creating a static signature and passing in the field you want to return.

```
protected $signature = 'env:return {field}';
```

This will allow you to type `php artisan env:return APP_DEBUG`.

You can retrieve the input like so:

```
public function handle()
{
    $envVariable = $this->argument('field');

    //
}
```

You can then write some code to output the field, perhaps something like:

```
$this->info(env($envVariable));
```

This could all be condensed down into something like the below, as an example only:

```
protected $signature = 'env:return {field}';

public function handle()
{
    $this->info(env($this->argument('field')));
}
```

I would suggest you read the docs I linked above as this will help you understand what is happening here a lot more.

This should get you started though, and you can then shape it to be exactly what you need.

Comment: The only problem was that php artisan env already exists so i renamed it to 'envfile'